# std::find, std::count_if, with vector of unique ptr

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have a `vector` of `unique_ptr` elements:

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vect;`

I need to find a particular element in this vector. How can this be achieved?

I need to check if the element with value 3 is present or not.

Comment: You could write a compare function (or lambda) that dereferences the `std::unique_ptr<int>` and checks the value:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: What is wrong with `find_if`?

Comment: A (fairly) simple `auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](const std::unique_ptr<int>& x) { return *x == 3; });` would suffice.

Comment: Why are you using a `vector` of `unique_ptr<int>` elements in the first place, and not a `vector` of `int` elements? In the latter case, `std::find()` would then work: `auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);`